# How to write Java code inside Oracle procedure

Tags: java, oracle, mutual-authentication, java-stored-procedures, oracle19c

I have created a Java source and compiled it and wrapped it in an Oracle 19c procedure with the jdk+jre 1.8.0._201. I'm connecting to a suite that uses TLS 1.2 with mutual authentication(with a private key).
I have already set java permissions using dbms_java.grant_permission.

This is the java code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE and COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED  "Test" AS


import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
public class Test{
    public static void test(String[] body,String[] result, String[] response){
        String s=body[0];
        String lenn = Integer.toString(s.length()); 
        result[0]="ok";
        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
        try  {
           String keyPath = "C:\\me\\keystore.jks";
           String keyPass = "123";
           String keyType = "JKS";
           System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyPath);
           System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyPass);
           System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", keyType);
           URL url = new URL("URL"); 
           HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           con.setRequestMethod("POST");
           con.setDoOutput( true );
           con.connect();
           //----------send body
           OutputStreamWriter writer = new 
                  OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
           writer.write(s);
           writer.flush();
           writer.close();
           //--------- reading the response
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
                  InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
           String inputLine;
           StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
           while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                buff.append(inputLine);
           }
           response[0]=buff.toString();
           con.disconnect();
      } catch(Exception ex) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            ex.printStackTrace(pw);
            result[0]=sw.toString();
      }
   } 
}
/
show errors
/
```

I tried all I could but with no luck
I got the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: connect failed, 10022
An invalid argument was
supplied.
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79
)
        at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        a
t
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:2
06)
        at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:255)
        at
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at
sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at
sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at
sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(A
bstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java
:1156)
        at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:
1050)
        at
sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDe
legateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl
.java:162)
        at Test.west(Test:27)
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This is the way i have created the oracle procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure test (body IN out VARCHAR2,result in OUT VARCHAR2,resp in OUT VARCHAR2)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'Test.test(java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[])';
```

calling the procedure

```
calling the procedure:
set serveroutput on
declare
body varchar2(32767);
resp varchar2(32767);
result varchar2(32767);
begin
body:='xml text ..........';
test(body,result,resp);
dbms_output.put_line(result);
dbms_output.put_line(resp);
dbms_output.put_line(length(resp));
end;
/
```

Comment: `URL url = new URL("URL");` is not a valid URL to connect to.

Comment: Also, Oracle restricts network access by stored procedures. The DBA will need to create an Access Control List and set permissions for the owner of the procedure (assuming it has definer's rights) before it will be able to access any network resources.

Comment: Its a valid url i wrote url as “url” because stackoverflow policy’s also i have created the acl and grant connect and assign a privilege for the user